Having an issue with my DNS not showing my CNAME and TXT records dont know what to do
so im having a bit of an issue with namecheap and my DNS. So for context me and a friend are trying to get email verification up for a project were working on and so we went ahead and set up a domain with namecheap. Now my issue is that the CNAME and TXT records do not show up in a DNS lookup which is making it impossible to for amazon SES to verify us. At first glance do you see anything that could point to what I did wrong (maybe I put it in incorrectly idk im a noob at this) Or if you know of some settings I should check in order to understand why my records arent showing (The A records show up fine its just everything else)
Not sure what to try tbh

The TXT records are showing up here fine – are you sure you weren't just looking at outdated cached data? DNS doesn't just cache data – the absence of a record is cached too, for however long the 'SOA' MINTTL says, so if you "test" query a record before actually adding it, this is going to happen...

You have provided evidence that you created A and TXT records. Check. You have stated that "they do not show up in a DNS lookup". Check. But you have provided no evidence that they do not show up in an NS lookup. What Method(s) did you use to check these records are not showing? Also, most dns providers clearly state that it may take up to 24 hrs (in most cases). And your TTL is set to "automatic" so we don't know how long your cache will ignore the new record.
